# Ember: returning just one record using something other than an id

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Let's say that I want to have URLs like `/users/JoshSmith` for maximum readability/shareability.

I set up my `Router`:

`this.resource('user', path: '/users/:username')`

And my route:

```
var UserRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    debugger
    return this.store.find('user', { username: params.username });
  }
});
```

But this `findQuery` function actually returns an array, since it's calling `/users?username=` instead of calling `/users/:username` like I would normally do.

I'm a little lost as to how I should be handling this; I'm assuming there's a convention out there, I just can't find it.

Comment: Are your slugs guaranteed to be unique?  If so, simply use them as the `id`.  If not, then a returned collection is probably appropriate.

Comment: Will Ember confuse the username with the id? Like when computing relations? And you just mean `this.store.find('user', params.username)` with `this.resource('user', path: '/users/:username')`?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested here: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/find-by-different-property/2479

Just override serialize on your route.

```
var UserRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('user', { username: params.username });
  },
  serialize: function(model) {
    return { username: model.get('username') };
  }
});
```

This replaces the default which looks like this:

```
serialize: function(model) {
  // this will make the URL `/posts/12`
  return { post_id: model.id };
}
```

Source: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_serialize

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem as well, `findQuery` always returns a record array. The way I got around this was to simply change my `model` hook in the router to

```
model: function(params) {
 return this.store.find('user', { username: params.username }).then(function(users) {
    return users.get('firstObject');
 });
}
```